# Decode HTML Entities in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a record in the database like: `<script src="here is link"><&#47;script>`.

It's regexp for convert slash to special HTML char: `string.replace(/\<\/script\>/g, '<&#47;script>');`

Then I output it to the page.

It's result after output:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">

    <&#47;script>

</script>
```

Why outputs HTML char? I need convert it again with regexp?

Comment: And why would you have a script tag inside a script tag ?

Comment: @adeneo, I need to save all scripts URLs on the page to database.

User can include a JS framework to the page and save it. After reload page they should be uploaded.

Comment: You want to save the URL of each `<script>` tag?

Comment: I don't know why there's so much confusion over this question. It's pretty clear. The database output is being rendered as an HTML entity rather than a slash.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes, it's desirable.

Comment: @isherwood - Well, the output seems to be a script tag containing a script tag, which is a little confusing, and probably not valid.

Comment: Of course it's not, which is the point of the question. Why is the closing script tag being duplicated in different forms?

Comment: @Isherwood, I'd definitely disagree over the question being 'pretty clear,' especially given the comment from the OP to my previous comment.

Comment: @isherwood - Then it's plain wrong, and should be asked as a serverside question, for instance in PHP you'd use html_entity_decode before outputting the script tag. It's a bit late to try and fix the script tag on the clientside ?

Comment: @isherwood, I'm pass a variable from server to the client-side. 

In client side I have this code: script var variable = #{code}; (Jade)

In a variable can be javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these JavaScript functions:

```
function decodeHTMLEntities(str) {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  });
};

var encodeHtmlEntity = function(str) {
  var buf = [];
  for (var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
  }
  return buf.join('');
};

alert(decodeHTMLEntities('<&#47;script>'))
```

***DEMO*** http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/6pXmn/3/

***SRC*** https://gist.github.com/CatTail/4174511