# Prevent UrlFetchApp creating special entities

Tags: html, google-apps-script, html-entities, urlfetch

Is there any way to prevent Apps Script URlFetchApp from creating special characters? For example on a webpage there might be an apostrophe but when I look in the fetched page source that apostrophe would be written as  &#x27;

Answer (score 1):

Use this `decode` function to decode your string:

```
function myFunction(str) { 
  var str = "&#x27;&#60;a&#62;Content &#169; &#60;#&#62;&#38;&#60;&#38;#&#62;# &#60;/a&#62;"
  var decoded = decode(str);
  Logger.log(decoded)
}

function decode(str) {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  }).replace(/(&#x(\d+);)/g, function(match, str1) {
    var hex  = match.toString().match(/(\d+)/g)[0];
    var str = '';
    for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
      str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
    }
    return str;   
  });
}
```

This will decode the HTML entities in JavaScript. Combined both my references. Decodes ones with x prepended and the others without.

#### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23270912/16132436
- https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/hex+to+ascii+function+javascript